# HTA and VBS dynamic list and opening file in list

Tags: vbscript, hta

First off new here and programming in general. I am trying to build an hta that can load various vbs scripts from an outside folder to make it more modular. I am current getting stuck at trying to open the vbs from my dynamic list. How do I open the file in my dynamic list? And also how do I pass a variable to the file?  This is what I currently have:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>My HTML application</title>
<HTA:APPLICATION
APPLICATIONNAME="My HTML application"
ID="MyHTMLapplication"
VERSION="1.0"/>
</head>

<script language="VBScript">

Sub Window_OnLoad
Dim FolderPath 

'folder to be searched for files 
Dim objFSO 
Dim objFolder 
Dim colFiles 
Dim objFile
Dim objOption
FolderPath = "%PathToScripts%"
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(FolderPath)
Set colFiles = objFolder.Files

For Each objFile in colFiles
Set objOption = Document.createElement("OPTION")
    objOption.Text = objFile.Name
    objOption.Value = objFile.Name
    mylistbox.Add(objOption)
Next
End Sub

Sub RunProgram 
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    objShell.Run objOption
End Sub



</script>

<body bgcolor="white">

<!--Add your controls here-->

<select name="mylistbox" size=10>
</select>

<input type="button" value="SingleSelect" onclick="RunProgram" name="RunScript">


<!--{{InsertControlsHere}}-Do not remove this line-->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

***Question 1: How do I open the file in my dynamic list?***

First, you need to retrieve the selected value from your list. For single-selection lists, you can just query the `Value` property of the `<select>` element:

```
strFile = mylistbox.Value
```

Since *nothing* may be selected, it's always a good idea to test the result to make sure you got something:

```
If Len(strFile) > 0 Then
```

Also, it looks like you're just showing the file *name* in the list, not the file *path*, which is fine, but you'll need the full file path if you want to run the file later. So you have a couple of options, here. `Option 1:` Make `FolderPath` a global constant instead of a local variable so that you can access it from your `RunProgram()` routine. `Option 2:` Take advantage of the `Value` property of `<option>` elements to store the full path for each list item while still just displaying the file name. Here's how to do the latter:

```
Set objOption = Document.createElement("OPTION")
    objOption.Text = objFile.Name
    objOption.Value = objFile.Path    ' Changed from objFile.Name to objFile.Path
    mylistbox.Add(objOption)
Next
```

Now that you have the full path to your script, you can run it. This is what your `RunProgram()` routine could look like:

```
Sub RunProgram()

    ' Get the selected value. This will be a full file path.
    strFile = mylistbox.Value

    ' Make sure something was selected.
    If Len(strFile) > 0 Then

        ' Run the script file.
        Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        objShell.Run Chr(34) & strFile & Chr(34)

    End If

End Sub
```

Note: `Chr(34)` is used to add double quotes around the file name in case it contains spaces.

***Question 2: How do I pass a variable to the file?***

This is where things get a little trickier. Though you can run a VBScript directly using the `Shell.Run` command (as we did above), if you want to pass an argument to the script, you need to run it explicitly using one of the scripting engine executables.

```
objShell.Run "wscript.exe " & Chr(34) & strFile & Chr(34) & " " & Chr(34) & strParam & Chr(34)
```

Here, we're using `wscript.exe` (the "GUI" version of the Windows Scripting Host) to explicitly run our script file. We're surrounding our file with double quotes, as we did above. And, finally, we're adding a space to separate the "command" from the parameter. For completeness, we're also adding double quotes around the parameter in case it contains spaces as well.